# How to display the chemistry formula in the html input?

Tags: javascript, html, input, autocomplete, chemistry

My input box is set as autocomplete.
The list items are chemistry formulas with subscripts.
I can only show the formulas on the dropdown selections.
I want to show the formula format in the input box.
[Dropdown List with subscripted items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu0rH.png)

I want like as following.
[Expected format in the input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzC5r.png)

Is there anyone who has experienced this? or anyone who can resolve this?

Comment: Normal input elements are not capable of displaying them in the way you want, but it is be possible with a [contenteditable element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) and some javascript.

Comment: If it's just numbers, you can use unicode.